# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage custom render invalid cast exception

Tags: android, xamarin, custom-renderer

I am writing a custom renderer for master detail page. And I get a invalid cast exception in the main activity.

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            //ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage), typeof(CustomRenderer))]
namespace App3.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class CustomRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {

        public CustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you reformat you code so that the markdown is unbroken

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

04-12 09:56:23.588 D/Mono    (11599): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib64/liblog.so'.
04-12 09:56:23.589 D/Mono    (11599): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib64/liblog.so'.
04-12 09:56:23.589 D/Mono    (11599): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib64/liblog.so' ('/system/lib64/liblog.so').

Comment: I cannot paste the whole error as it exceeds the length

Comment: 04-12 09:56:23.661 I/MonoDroid(11599): System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
04-12 09:56:23.661 I/MonoDroid(11599):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.MasterDetailContainer.get_FragmentManager () [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\MasterDetailContainer.cs:27 
04-12 09:56:23.661 I/MonoDroid(11599):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.MasterDetailContainer.AddChildView (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement childView) [0x0007c] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\MasterDetailContainer.cs:98

Comment: I checked your code and you have inherited from public class MainActivity:global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity and I am from FormsApplicationActivity.

Comment: Sorry for late, please "@" me, so I can see your comment immediately. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318416/migrating-to-formsapplicationactivity-causing-exceptions-in-navigationrenderer), check your render's namespace, make sure its not `AppCompat`.

Comment: yes .. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple demo for MasterDetailPage on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/MDTest), you can refer to it to custom your `MasterDetailPage`.